# Using ACF fields from one post type in another post type based on choice?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

So I will preface this with being new to Wordpress/ACF but can do the basics.

I can set up fields and post types and query through them and do loops.

This I am not sure how to do.

I have a post type of properties that each have an assigned contact our of 3 people. I would like to enable to client in the backend when creating a property to be able to choose the assigned contact from a dropdown menu or a set of checkboxes.

That when a visitor clicks on that property the front end displays the contacts name email and phone number which are fields from the contacts bio post type.

I have a relationship field set up to go through the Bios and return the IDs but not sure where to go from there.

Thanks!

[Base Fields For Contact Bio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Say5.png)

[image: Relationship Fields]

Answer (score 1):

If relation returns selected post's ID you can easy use `get_fields($post_id)` or `get_field($key, $post_id)`.

Comment: Okay so how would I go about setting up like a Dropdown or Checkboxes for the client to choose the assigned contact?

Comment: Try to use Post Object with value "Select Multiple Values ?  yes"

Comment: So I see on the Property page I can choose from a list of the related fields. So it would just be running a loop then?

Comment: @OMGDrAcula sorry, cant understand a question

Comment: So in the backend of wordpress I chose the specific relationship post for the property.

So now that it has a specific bio assigned to it I can pull that posts fields correct?

Comment: @OMGDrAcula Of course,  then loop through all returned ids and user get_fields or get _field function.